# Failed install of 14.04 computer shut down during install but after download

Tags: upgrade

I accidentally shut off my computer during an upgrade from a previous version (I think it was 12.10).  It was after the download was complete, but only about 15% through the install process.  I have some photos, so a wipe of the partition and starting over is out of the question.  I am dual booting with Windows 7, and it is a company computer that only barely tolerates my venture away from Windows.

Comment: You're allowed to make software changes on a company computer?

Comment: Where you upgrading Ubuntu or installing Ubuntu?

Comment: @Braiam OP States it was an upgrade (may 12.10).  But I guess we need to know if the pictures are on the Ubuntu partition or the Windows partition.

Answer (score 1):

#### Recover Pictures

First item of business is to recover high-value files.  You haven't specified how you managed the boot partitions, or if you're using GRUB as the boot manager.

It is my hope that only the Ubuntu partition is damaged.

1. Remove the installation media (CD/DVD/USB) and try to
   boot.
2. If GRUB is functioning, you'll have to toggle through choices about which OS to boot, choose Windows 7.
3. Insert a blank dvd or attach USB storage, whatever - and offload (backup) your important items.

#### Re-Attempt Installation

- Use Ubuntu to manage your partitions and **delete the partially-installed Ubuntu partition**
- Reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 by having your computer connected to stable power or an [UPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply)
- I also recommend that you connect to internet via ethernet cable because USB Wireless will lose functionality during the install process.

  - This will allow updates to be downloaded during the install
  - It may also allow for driver's to be automatically installed

Comment: No need to delete the "partially-installed Ubuntu partition" , see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score 0):

Recovering from failed upgrades can be difficult and your first step should be data recovery.

You should be able to perform data recovery by booting Windows or an Ubuntu live USB and recovering the data.

Mount the Ubuntu partition and copy the data. If you are using wubi, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_the_Wubi_files_from_Windows.3F

Once you have a back up of your data, do a fresh install of Ubuntu WITHOUT formatting your root partition and your data in /home will be preserved.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

> Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). **This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition**

Once you are up and running, moving forward, be sure to have a working backup of all data that is important to you.